# users can not login by custom login model django

Tags: django

i am going to use a dual authentication system (email, username). when i create users by "createsuperuser" users can login but when i create users inside admin panel of django user can not login and also i noticed the user's password which is made in admin panel is not hashed in DB!

**backend.py:**

```
class EmailBackend(backends.ModelBackend):

def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
    if username is None:
        username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
    try:
        user = UserModel.objects.get(Q(username__iexact=username) | Q(email__iexact=username))
    except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
        UserModel().set_password(password)
    else:
        if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
            return user
    return super().authenticate(request, username, password, **kwargs)
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Comment: Show us the Admin code, please. You cannot login because the password is not hashed, and it's not hashed due to the admin form having just a plain text input

Comment: thanks a lot... u were right i have forgotten to complete "add_form" and "form" in admin.py